# MongoDB group by query running from Spring MongoTemplate does not return sum

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data, aggregation-framework

I have the following query which works fine when running from MongoDB shell:

```
db.feedback.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
           _id: {
               year: { $year: '$receivedDate' }, 
               month: { $month: '$receivedDate' }
           }, 
           count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

It returns dates (year, month) and their sum.

However, when I run the same query from Spring's MongoTemplate I get the date, and the sum is always null:

```
private static final String QUERY_STATS_BY_MONTH = "{
    aggregate: 'feedback', 
    pipeline: ([
        {
            $group:{
                _id: {
                    year: { $year: '$receivedDate' }, 
                    month: { $month: '$receivedDate' }
                }, 
                count: { $sum: 1 }
            }
        } 
    ])";
    ....


    CommandResult commandResult = mongoTemplate.executeCommand(QUERY_STATS_BY_DAY);
    BasicDBList dbList = (BasicDBList) commandResult.get(QUERY_RESULT);
    Iterator<Object> it = dbList.iterator();
    List<FeedbackDateAggregation> res = new ArrayList();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        DBObject dbObject = (DBObject) it.next();
        res.add(mongoTemplate.getConverter().read(FeedbackDateAggregation.class, dbObject));
    }
    return res;
```

My domain classes are:

```
public class FeedbackDateAggregation {

    private StatsDate id;
    private Long count;

    public Long getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(Long count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public StatsDate getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(StatsDate id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class StatsDate {

    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;
    private int week;

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public void setMonth(int month) {
        this.month = month;
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(int day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public int getWeek() {
        return week;
    }

    public void setWeek(int week) {
        this.week = week;
    }
}
```

The StatsDate are retrieved, but count is always null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try projecting the fields you want to use as the group by keys first by using the **[SpEL `andExpression`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation.examples.example5)** in the projection operation and then group by the new fields in the group operation:

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    project("id")
        .andExpression("month(receivedDate)").as("month")
        .andExpression("year(receivedDate)").as("year"),
    group("year", "month").count().as("count")
);

AggregationResults<FeedbackDateAggregation> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(
    agg, 
    "feedback", 
    FeedbackDateAggregation.class
);
List<FeedbackDateAggregation> res = results.getMappedResults();
```

---

In the above a new aggregation via the **`newAggregation`** static factory method is created to which you pass a list of aggregation operations. These aggregate operations define the aggregation pipeline of your Aggregation.

In the first step you project the fields from the input collection by using the **[SpEL `andExpression`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation.examples.example5)** with the project operation.

In the second step you use the group operation to define a group for each `"year"` and `"month"`-value for which you aggregate the occurrence count via the `count()` aggregation operator and collect the result in a new field called `"count"`.

Finally call the **`aggregate()`** Method on the MongoTemplate in order to let MongoDB perform the actual aggregation operation with the created Aggregation as an argument.

Comment: I tried it but got a NullPointerException during parsing: at com.mongodb.util.JSONSerializers$MapSerializer.serialize(JSONSerializers.java:321)

Answer (score 2):

This is the idiomatic way of doing aggregation queries using spring template. You don't need to access the low level `CommandResult` mongo api, only need for advance use.

Makes use of `AggregationOperation` as the operator `$year` and `$month` are not supported out of box in the spring group stage yet.

```
AggregationOperation group = new AggregationOperation() {
  @Override
  public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext context) {
    return new BasicDBObject(
            "$group", new BasicDBObject(
              "_id", new BasicDBObject(
                "year", new BasicDBObject("$year", "$receivedDate")).append(
                "month", new BasicDBObject("$month", "$receivedDate"))).append(
            "count", new BasicDBObject("$sum", 1)));
   }
};
```

`newAggregation` is the static helper method which takes a list of pipeline stages.

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(group);
```

Finally, mongo template aggregate method to run the query.

```
List<FeedbackDateAggregation> res = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "feedback", FeedbackDateAggregation.class).getMappedResults();
```

Generated Query:

```
{
    "aggregate": "__collection__",
    "pipeline": [{
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "year": {
                    "$year": "$receivedDate"
                },
                "month": {
                    "$month": "$receivedDate"
                }
            },
            "count": {
                "$sum": 1
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The id object (date + month) is null, and count is always 0.

Comment: I saw it and even without the extra $, it's not working.. :(

Comment: it should work. Added the generated json to the post.. may be its failing while mapping it to pojo

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I used an old version of Fongo (fake mongo for tests). Once I tried it on a real MongoDB, it worked like a charm. When I updated my Fongo version, it worked as well.
I also had to change my domain objects. I have now a domain object that includes day, week, month, year, count.